# Is it possible to pass a javascript array through GET and access it through $_GET at the other end..?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, get

I have a javascript array say `jsArr[]`. I want this array to be passed to a php page through the get method. Something like `nextPage.php?arr=jsArr[]`.

There I should be able to access the array like `$arr[] = $_GET[arr]` and perform operations like `foreach($arr as $key => $val)`

Is it possible...?

Thanks a lot in advance...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need to change your url to be:

```
nextPage.php?arr[]=js&arr[]=js2
```

for example.

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

outputs: `array(1) { ["arr"]=>  array(2) { [0]=>  string(2) "js" [1]=>  string(3) "js2" } }`

Comment: Should i get it like "$_GET[arr]" in the php page...?

Comment: Technically, `$_GET['arr']`. It will work without quotes because PHP stupidly treats unknown constants as unquoted strings, but that should never be relied upon. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php

Answer (score 21):

You can also use [JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html) (JS parser [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js))

JS:

```
  var arr = [1, 4, 9];
  var url = '/page.php?arr=' + JSON.stringify(arr);
  window.location.href = url;
```

PHP:

```
$arr = isset($_REQUEST['arr']) ? json_decode($_REQUEST['arr']) : array();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be [jQuery's serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: Can't use this plugin... i don't want to submit a whole form... just need to pass this array...